# Are some burgers in Japan made from human excrement?

Tags: nutrition, japan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Has a meat substitute from human feces been developed in Japan?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/has-a-meat-substitute-from-human-feces-been-developed-in-japan)

Please look at **[this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1N6QfuIh0g)**.  Is there any evidence that this is real or **[fake](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyRZdMBwojU)**?

Comment: -1 for eww factor... do you really want to know the answer to this question... keep in mind you can never unknow it.

Comment: Am I correct in my assumption that human excrement is the resulting nutritionless byproduct of our bodies processing the food we eat (digestion, burning energy, etc.)?  If so, then is it also reasonable to assume that such a meat substitute would be lacking in nutritional value?

Answer (score 2):

Here an article about [meat made from human excrement](http://sanfrancisco.ibtimes.com/articles/164958/20110617/japanese-scientist-makes-poop-burger-mitsuyuki-ikeda.htm).  This was picked up by the mainstream press.  However, here's another article from [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/nadiaarumugam/2011/07/08/meat-made-from-human-feces-hoax-or-japans-best-new-invention/) by someone who actually tried to research and find out if it was true.  Seems that mainstream press picked up everything from the existence of the youtube video, and that there wasn't actually any official press release from the supposed scientist.  The author of the second article states that after trying to find any real evidence of this, seems to turn up nothing.

Comment: Many hoaxes have been picked up by the mainstream press, like the Loch Ness monster... Often mainstream media prefer to create audience than checking their sources.

Comment: @FrostyZ seems like you may be right. This article was everywhere, hard to believe that almost nobody did their research.  What is the purpose of the news if nobody bothers to check the facts.

Comment: ever heard [sensationalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensationalism) it's all for the moneyz

Comment: The scientist in the [first YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1N6QfuIh0g) is holding a pointer stick with a funny looking plastic hand on the end that looks like a child's toy -- when I saw this, I wondered if the scientist really wanted to be taken seriously.

Comment: @Kibbee - If they check their facts and find out they were wrong then they are committing libel.  If they did not know they were wrong then they are just reporting a story.

Comment: @Chad hence cover-your-ass phrases like "Sources say..." or  "We've heard that..."